# Retain cutcopy mode after macro

Tags: vba, excel

So I have this problem which I can't wrap my head around.
I have a an excel report that executes an important macro on sheet_activate, and as we all know macros cancel CutCopyMode.

Therefore, if I want to copy & paste something from a different file into my report, it never works because as soon as I activate my report it runs the macro and cancels the CutCopyMode from the other file.

Things I have tried:

**1) save cutcopymode value and re-activate it after the macro:**

```
Dim tmpCT
tmpCT = Application.CutCopyMode

...

Application.CutCopyMode = tmpCT
```

the problem: it doesnt work.

**2) save the data from the clipboard and re-insert it as plain text object after the macro is done running:**

```
Dim DataClipBoard As String
Dim clipboardData As DataObject
Dim RangeCopied As Range
Set RangeCopied = Selection
DataClipBoard = ClipBoard_GetData
Application.CutCopyMode = False

...

Set clipboardData = New DataObject
With clipboardData
    .SetText DataClipBoard
    .PutInClipboard
End With
Set clipboardData = Nothing
```

The problem: it's plain text and doesn't retain formats/links/etc.

I'd appreciate any input you can give me on this issue.

Comment: Saving `.CutCopyMode` will just store if it's "Cut" or "Copy", not the range you wanted to Cut/Copy.  You might be better starting your macro with `If Application.CutCopyMode>0 Then Exit Sub` to skip it if you are in Cut/Copy mode

Comment: @chronocidal thanks, i know the values of cutcopymode are simply either cut or copy, i was just saving it to account for cut/copy and set it to the relevant value as an attempt to "reactivate" the cutcopy mode, doesnt work. and unfortunately, skipping the macro wont do because i need the macro to run, and i need to keep the copied range reference in the clipboard after the macro finishes.

Comment: You can try an approach where when you macro runs, if cutcopy mode is on, paste the contents into a hidden worksheet. At the end of your macro, re-copy from your hidden worksheet and then destroy the worksheet

Comment: @QHarr If your macro *changes **any** cell values* then the clipboard is lost: `Private Sub Worksheet_Activate(): Debug.Print "Activate Event": Me.Cells(1,1).Formula=Me.Cells(1,1).Formula:End Sub`

Answer (score 2):

The following macro will return the current range for Cut/Copy, which you can then store in a Range variable and re-Cut/Copy after your other workbook is open.

(Personally, I think that `Application.CutCopyRange` should be a built-in special variable to do this.)

```vb
Function CutCopyRange() As Range
    Dim StoredMode As XlCutCopyMode
    StoredMode = Application.CutCopyMode
    If StoredMode < 1 Then Exit Function 'Null case
    If StoredMode = xlCut Then
        'Disappointing, since Clipboard lets you Paste a copy of a cut range...
        MsgBox "Unfortunately, Worksheet.Paste(Link:=True) only works for Copy-mode.", vbCritical
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Dim ScreenUpdating As Boolean, DisplayAlerts As Boolean, EnableEvents As Boolean

    ScreenUpdating = Application.ScreenUpdating
    DisplayAlerts = Application.DisplayAlerts
    EnableEvents = Application.EnableEvents

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.EnableEvents = False

    'This makes us loose our Cut/Copy mode...
    With Worksheets.Add
        .Paste Link:=True
        Set CutCopyRange = Range(Range(Replace(Selection.Cells(1, 1).Formula, "=", "")), _
            Range(Replace(Selection.Cells(Selection.Rows.Count, Selection.Columns.Count).Formula, "=", "")))
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        .Delete
    End With

    'Restore Cut/Copy mode to what it was before the previous block
    Select Case StoredMode
        Case xlCut
            CutCopyRange.Cut
        Case xlCopy
            CutCopyRange.Copy
    End Select

    Application.DisplayAlerts = DisplayAlerts
    Application.ScreenUpdating = ScreenUpdating
    Application.EnableEvents = EnableEvents
End Function
```

Comment: its a clever approach, i will look into it but i want to point out that you should turn events off before adding the new sheet because my code runs at sheet_activate and your code while adding a new sheet, will trigger the new sheet's activate sub and will enter an infinite recursion.

Comment: Only if you put it in the `sheet_activate` event.  If it is in the macro that calls the sheet activation then you don't get a loop (e.g. `Set rngCopy = CutCopyRange(): Sheet1.Activate: rngCopy.Copy Destination:=Sheet1.Cells(1,1)`)